# Is there some way with which i can apply css dynamically to my child component?

Tags: css, angular

I have a component which is reusable. This component is called from parent component multiply times and sometimes the background page of the parent component is white and sometimes is black.

My child component generates form tags dynamycally - inputs,selects, textarea.

That means i can't have `fixed` styles in my css in my component for my content.

So when when the background page is white - i have one style for my inputs - for example black background. When the background page is black i have another style for my inputs - for example white bacgrkound.

To solve this is issue:

**i tried**

Adding input property in my child component ts file

```
  @Input()
  public cssTemplate;
```

in html

```
    <div [ngClass]="{'form-group-white-bg': cssTemplate == 'white', 'form-group-dark-bg': cssTemplate == 'black'}">
        <label for=""></label>
....
```

**In the CHILD component i am sending value for input property depending on where the child component is called**

if it is called on page with white background

```
<app-form-group cssTemplate="black" formControlName="address">
</app-form-group>
```

if it is called on black bacgrkound

```
<app-form-group cssTemplate="white" formControlName="address" [data]="{ field: 'address', label: 'Address' }">
</app-form-group>
```

but the problem here is that sometimes on my parent component this component is called multiply times
on one page can be called 12 times where i need 10 inputs and 2 selects

on other page can be called 15 times etc.

That means that i need to repat my self 15 times

```
<app-form-group cssTemplate="white" formControlName="address">
</app-form-group>

<app-form-group cssTemplate="white" formControlName="someItherControlName">
</app-form-group>
```

and everywhere to put `cssTemplate="white"`.

`ngFor` is not an optin because this child component is called multiply times but not on same place in the HTML structure in the parent.

How can i solve this `DRY`?

Comment: You could use the `@ContentChildren()` decorator and set the value manually for each `<app-form-group>` and after you've updated all of them manually call detectChanges on a `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: How do you create `form-group` and controls inside of this group? Could you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

you can add styles in your styles.css (the styles general for all the application). If e.g. you has

```
.white h1{
  color:red;
}
.black h1{
  color:green;
}
```

You can use [ngClass] in the "parent"

```
<div [ngClass]="toogle?'white':'black'">
  <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
</div>
<button (click)="toogle=!toogle">toogle</button>
```

See [stackblitz][1]

NOTE: I used the way `[ngClass]="expresion"` (where expresion use conditional operator) better that `[ngClass]="{'classname1':condition;'classname2':!condition}"`

**Update** about your comment "how can i prevent repeating my self on child call", really I don't understand so much. I don't know if you want to make a directive like, e.g.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'hello', //<--the selector is the selector of the component
  exportAs: 'helloDiv'
})
export class HelloDirective implements OnInit{
  constructor(@Self() private component:HelloComponent,private dataService:DataService){
  }
  ngOnInit(){
     console.log(this.component.name)
     this.dataService.theme.subscribe(res=>{
       this.component.theme=res;
     })
  }
}
```

This allow to "extends" the component -in the stackblitz the variable "theme" change-
[1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjwxyq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Tnx for your response. But i will still need to pass `cssTemplate="white"` on every child component call to tell if it is white or black.That is the problem of my question - not the css.

Comment: why? If you use the styles.css the styles is applied to all the aplication. The idea is get out the styles "form-group-white-bg" and "form-group-black-bg" of your child component. I imagine that will be like `.form-group-white-bg label{..}.form-group-white-bg input{...}`. it's equal put the "div" outside the child component -well, if you use child/descendant combinators or adjacent sibling combinator, really you need rethinking the .css-

Comment: It is okay what you say, i mean you did not give anser of that how can i prevent repeating my self on child call

Answer (score 1):

## Styling Child Components depending on Parent Component

There are two approaches I commonly take in this scenario

1. :ng-deep - create a style rule based on a class which is set in your parent component
2. utilize `@ContentChildren()` to set a property directly on your child components and call `detectChanges()` manually after the change.

To adopt the first solution you need to exercise greater care in your css naming rules, as  using ng-deep obviously breaks the isolation of those style rules.

To adopt the second approach needs some considering due to it technically circumventing the standard input/output flow in Angular and thus can be a bit of a surprise "undocumented behavior" for any other maintainers of the application.

I'm a bit on the fence whether I prefer one approach over the other. The first approach seems more trivial to me, but it can also cause unintended style rule overwrites, while the second approach involves a lot more scripting and seems a bit of a hack.

### Approach 1: ng-deep

1. Give your parent component an input and update a class on a block-element wrapping your `<ng-content>`.
2. create your desired style rules in your child component.

```js
// parent component
@Component(...)
export class FooParent {
 @Input() bgStyle: 'light' | 'dark' = 'light';
}
```

```html
<!-- parent component template -->
<div class="parent" [ngClass]="{light: bgStyle == 'light', dark: bgStyle == 'dark'}">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

```css
// child.css
::ng-deep .light .child-container {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

::ng-deep .dark .child-container {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

My targeted element in the example is `.child-container`, you would write a similar style rule for each element you want to affect.

## Approach 2: Using ContentChildren to pass along a value

1. Add a `@ContentChildren()` decorator to your parent component which selects for your child components.
2. inject a `ChangeDetectorRef`
3. implement ngAfterViewInit to loop through each child and set the value
4. call `detectChanges()` once done.
5. add the `ngClass` directive as normally in your child component.

#### Parent

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() bgStyle: 'light' | 'dark' = 'light';
  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent) childComponents!: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  constructor(private change: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if ('bgStyle' in changes) {
      this.updateChildComponents();
    }
  }

  updateChildComponents() {
    this.childComponents.forEach(child => {
      child.bgStyle = this.bgStyle;
    });
    this.change.detectChanges();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateChildComponents();
  }

}
```

```
<!-- parent.component.html -->
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

#### Child

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['child.component.scss']
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  bgStyle: 'light' | 'dark' = 'light';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

```
<!-- child.component.html -->
<div [ngClass]="{light: bgStyle == 'light', dark: bgStyle == 'dark'}" class="child-container"></div>
```

```css
// child.component.css - you would apply styles as you needed obviously.
.child-container {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.light.child-container {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.dark.child-container {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

#### Usage

```html
<!-- any other template -->
<parent>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

**Note:** If you are creating the `ChildComponent` directly in the `ParentComponent`'s own template you need to use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ContentChildren`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input property to create a css class map to pass on to ngClass. This object should be an object of string arrays.
It can be pretty much as complex and contain as many classes and rules as you need it too

```js
    @Input() color: 'white' | 'red' | 'hotpink' = 'white';

    classMap: any;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.updateClassMap();
    }

    updateClassMap() {
      this.classMap = {
        [this.color]: !!this.color, // Add this class if not null
      };
    }
```

Then in the Html simply pass it to ngClass

```html
    <div [ngClass]="classMap">
```

Comment: I still need to call my child component with same argument multiply times - color = 'white' etc.. That was my question

Comment: No you don't, you just pass the class map around to your child components. The class map should be created with the same logic that determines what color a child should have

Comment: Yes, i will need to pass again classmap on every child call !

Comment: I don't know your application, maybe looking into ngTemplateOutlet could suit your needs then. But it is impossible to have dynamic content without passing it some form of input if it can't resolve the content on it's own